# would one have to import same file twice?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a models file.

From my views file I import the models file

From my views file I alter the models file in a particular function by adding an attribute.

If while still in the same function i then wish to access the new models attribute, would I then have to re-import the models file

Heres what im trying to accomplish

In my models file i have a bunch of attributes that measures and ranks peoples ability to lift weights. There are 10 different exercises that they can measure and rank themselves. I want them to mix and match the exercises and rankings. With 10 exercises this makes hundreds of ranking possibilities, something i dont wish to code in manually. And this is just for the weights section.

If somebody goes about finding out thier rank in any of the hundreds of possible ways, i want the code to check if the ranking attribute is there. If not, i want to add it to the mysql database as well as the models file.

```
for i in request.GET:
        a += i
        a += '+'
        b += i
        b += '_'

a = a.strip("+")
b = b.strip("_")
c = b + '_rank'

if c not in WeightsProfile.__doc__:


        shutil.move("models.py", "models.py"+"~")
        original = open("models.py"+"~", 'r')
        new = open("models.py", 'w')

        for line in original:
            new.write(line)
            if "Snatch_rank = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, default=0)" in line:
                new.write("    %s = models.IntegerField(max_length=30, default='0')" % c + '\n')

        new.close()
        original.close() 

        conn = mdb.connect('localhost', 'jamie', 'wiser9999', 'website')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("alter table mysite_weightsprofile add column %s integer not null; SET @rank=0; UPDATE mysite_weightsprofile SET %s = @rank:=@rank+1 order by %s DESC;" %  (c, c, a))
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
    else:
        pass
```

Is this bad practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not altering the "models file", your altering the in-memory representation of the model -- essentially monkey-patching your own code. So, no, you don't have to re-import anything -- in fact, if you could, you'd simply overwrite your changes -- but, this is bad, bad design. Perhaps if you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish, someone can tell you a better way to go about it.